# How to hook up infinitescroll.js with isotope.js for WordPress portfolio

Tags: jquery, wordpress, infinite-scroll, lightbox2

I've been working on making a portfolio with wordpress / isotope.js / Lightbox2 and am now trying to add infinitescroll.js to the mix, alas with no avail.

So far I've just got a mess of code...

Secondly, here is some of the code I have running.

```
//Isotope settings
var $container = jQuery( '#projects' );

$container.imagesLoaded( function() {   
    $container.isotope({    
        itemSelector : '.isotope',
        resizable : false,
        masonry : { columWidth: $container.width() / 3 }
    });

});

// infinite scroll
$container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : '#project-nav',
    nextSelector : '#project-nav a',
    itemSelector : '.isotope',
    loading: {
        finishedMsg: 'No more projects.',
        msgText: "Loading more projects ...",
        img: TEMPLATE_URI + '/images/loader.gif'
    }   
},

    function( newElements ) {   
        $container.isotope( 'appended', jQuery( newElements ));
    }

);
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: For starters, you include the infinitescroll plugin file after you call script.js..so should probably look into order of inclusion

Comment: @Ohgodwhy That does not appear to help any... I am really confused as to why this is not wanting to work!

Comment: Please show your HTML and any other relevant code.